# Storing files in Attachment datatype in Ms access using C#

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

I get this error

[image]

I don't understand why I keep getting this error since I don't even have any multi-valued field in my insert statement.

```
con = new OleDbConnection(cs);
            con.Open();

            string fnum = lblFNum.Text;               
            string num = lblPnum.Text.ToString();
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(lblFile.Text);
            string a = "INSERT INTO Documents([FileNumber], [ProjectID], [File]) VALUES('" + fnum + "','" + num + "','" + file + "')";

            cmd = new OleDbCommand(a);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.ExecuteReader();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Document Successfully Added", "Prompt", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

What code do I need to fix this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to save to the Database? The file name, byte stream, path ..? If you step through your code, and inspect the value of `a` at runtime, you should see what the issue is.

Comment: One attachment field can store multiple attachments, so it is a type of multi-valued field and can not be contained in an `INSERT`.

Comment: want I want to happen is to store the file itself to the database. This is actually for a Document Repository System. Basically just like a dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use parameter in your query, it will prevent SQL Injection.

Second, you are trying to put a `FileInfo` into the query, that doesn't work. You have to read the file into a byte[] and save that to the database.

Example:

```
var fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(lblFile.Text); // You should also check if file exists...

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Documents([FileNumber], [ProjectID], [File]) VALUES(@fileNumber, @projectId, @file)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileNumber", fnum);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@projectId", num);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file", fileData);
```

Comment: The file exists but this code still resulted to an error